# Azure Storage upload Bug

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-storage

I do not know if this is a bug or not, but I have made a Xamarin app, that will connect to Azure storage to upload a file.

It doesn't want to upload nd I get this error

[Azure service, to upload the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/841sT.png)

I made the same application, using a console app (for testing fester)

```
    var path = Path.Combine(projectPath, "universal.txt");

var fullpath = Path.GetFullPath(path);

var FileName = Path.GetFileName(fullpath);

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullpath)) {

    sw.WriteLine("Hello I want to  go to Universal tomorrow");
}


var AzureStorage = new BlobContainerClient(ConectionString, ContanerName);

var blob = AzureStorage.GetBlobClient(FileName);
await blob.UploadAsync(fullpath);
```

My file get uploaded to Azure

[File in  storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei4KG.png)

Comment: Does the exception have an inner exception? Post the complete exception.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images.  And as @mxmissile suggests, you need to drill down into the exception to see what other details it provides

Comment: there aren't any inner exception

System.TypeInitializationException
  Message=The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.Diagnostics.AzureCoreEventSource' threw an exception.

thaat is everything i get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these functions to upload a file from xamarin.

```
static CloudBlobContainer GetContainer(ContainerType containerType)
{
  var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Constants.StorageConnection);
  var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
  return client.GetContainerReference(containerType.ToString().ToLower());
}

public static async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(ContainerType containerType, Stream stream)
{
  var container = GetContainer(containerType);
  await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

  var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  var fileBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
  await fileBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

  return name;
}
```

OR

```
client = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnectionString);
containerClient = await client.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName);

blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
await containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(fileName, memoryStreamFile);
```

Comment: This is different from the OP's code. What, exactly, fixes their problem? You wrote new code in a new way, but didn't solve their error (at least, you didn't explain why they have an error)

Comment: I fixed it, you just had to include Azure.Core in the nugget packages, is weird how it doesn't install automatically, when you include Azure.Blob